# Close window botton - javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, browser, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the following:

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.close()" class="close"></a>
```

But when I try to click, the browser window wouldn't close. In fact there is no effect whatsoever.

- What should I use?
- Also, this is a rails application, and the site is built with bootstrap. What is a better way to close this browser window using rails routes (javascript, bootstrap are already in assets)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you open the window you're trying to close with `window.open()`? You're not allowed to arbitrarily close windows using JavaScript - that would get very annoying, very quickly. Your script can only close a window that it opened itself, or the current window if that was opened by another script.

See also: [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close).